# как информацию из массива передать в текст?

Tags: python, kivy

у меня есть 3 файла, один исходник с кодом, второй код для xlsx, третий сам файл xlsx. Данные берутся из файла xlsx и импортируются в исходный код , при попытки перенести данные , которые хранятся в массиве в код kivy.text он не срабатывает, в чём моя ошибка ?

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from test import batch_Names_wanted

KV = '''

Screen:

    NavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            Screen:
                name: "scr 2"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Успеваемость'
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
                        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                        md_bg_color: .2, .2, .2, 1
                        specific_text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "scr 2"
                        halign: "center"


'''

class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def text_up_1(self):
        text_1 = \
        '''
        как присвоить данные из batch_Names_wanted ?
        ''' 
        return text_1


TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

второй

```
import xlrd

excel_data_file = xlrd.open_workbook('./DATA.xlsx') # путь к файлу 
sheet = excel_data_file.sheet_by_index(0)# лист 1

batch_Names_wanted = [] #  массив
row_number = sheet.nrows  # количество строк


class xlrd():
    if row_number > 0: # проверка пуст он или нет 
        for row in range(0,row_number): # пробегаемся по всем строчкам 
            batch_Names_wanted.append(str(sheet.row(row)[1]).replace("text:", "").replace("'",""). replace(":"," "). replace("."," ").replace(" 0","").replace("empty","пустые данные")) # настройки 
    else:
        print(" Excel файл пуст или заполнен неверно !")
```

и сам 3 файл https://yadi.sk/i/iYCiHGyJuVq_aQ

Comment: во втором файле у вас не правильно оформлен class, и он не возвращает значение.

Comment: Мне использовать return ? Если да , то как правильно это сделать ?Благодарю заранее за ответ, с уважением !

Comment: Да, но не только return, гуглите функции и классы python